# After macOS updated to Ventura 13.3, these numbers are showing up in app launcher

Tags: macos, launchpad

Serial numbers have started showing in the app launcher after the Mac OS update.

How can these numbers be removed, so back to normal view.

[image: Screenshot of app launcher showing numbers]

Comment: Tip: you can take a screenshot with Command-Shift-3 or Command-Shift-4 instead of taking photos of a physical screen

Answer (score 23):

### Voice Over

I had the same experience on my Mac a few months ago, and it turned out that I had accidentally turned on Voice Over. (by pressing <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> probably).

The numbers that you see on your screen aren't serial numbers, they are there for you to say which apps or actions you want to open or do.

To disable Voice Over and therefore get rid of the numbers, simply press <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd><kbd>F5</kbd> simultaneously with your keyboard or, if you have Touch ID, hold down the <kbd>Command ⌘</kbd> key while pressing (not holding) the Touch ID button three times. (See [Turn VoiceOver on or off on Mac](https://support.apple.com/guide/voiceover/turn-voiceover-on-or-off-vo2682/mac) for more info and guidance on this)

---

While the microphone icon with "Sleep" below it could indicate that Voice Control is enabled, but the fact that there are the numbers you see next to apps show that Voice Over is the culprit.

Comment: I thought this was Voice Control rather than VoiceOver.

Comment: @ma1234 Voice Control doesn't show these numbers in Launchpad. But it does show the microphone icon, as Voice Over does.